# Why can't I run a Python project in C9IDE anymore?

Tags: python, django, cloud9-ide

When I create a new Python/Django project and then create a new file called test.py, I am unable to run test.py.

If I try to run my project it just runs a Django server and starts asking me to create a super user.

Mere minutes ago I was able to run a python project normally. Then I deleted the project and created it again and now it will only let me run the python file by right clicking the file manually and selecting run.

Comment: I think we just replied to an email of yours, please let me know if we can still help!

Comment: I've responded to your response to my ticket. It doesn't help me that you're saying my application is a Django application. If that's the case then how do I create a Python application?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new run configuration under the Run menu and set the default configuration in the project settings under the Cloud9 menu but personally I just run my Python app/script from the bash prompt so I can see the traceback if (or more like when) it crashes.